# Cypher - Convert graph result to list or JSON

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have the following Neo4j graph result.

[image: Neo4j graph result]

 I
'm using the multiple relationship `-[RELATED_TO*]-` command to obtain that.

```
Match(n:Comment)
MATCH(n)-[RELATED_TO*]-(d:Comment)
return n, d;
```

I want to display the results in a List where I could say that this answer comes from that answer, or in a JSON cascade file. What is the best approach to reach that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can return a JSON cascade structure using the [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) procedure `apoc.convert.toTree`. Take a look in this example:

Creating a sample data set:

```
CREATE (:Comment {id : 1})<-[:RELATED_TO]-(:Comment {id : 2})<-[:RELATED_TO]-(:Comment {id : 3})<-[:RELATED_TO]-(:Comment {id : 4})
```

Querying:

```
MATCH p = (n:Comment)<-[RELATED_TO*]-(d:Comment)
// I believe you are interested only in the "complete" path.
// That is: you are not interested in the sub path like (:Comment {id : 2})-[:RELATED_TO]->(:Comment {id : 3}).
// So this WHERE clause is used to avoid these sub paths.
WHERE NOT (n)-->() AND NOT (d)<--()
CALL apoc.convert.toTree([p]) yield value
RETURN value
```

The output:

```
{
  "_type": "Comment",
  "related_to": [
    {
      "_type": "Comment",
      "related_to": [
        {
          "_type": "Comment",
          "related_to": [
            {
              "_type": "Comment",
              "_id": 142701,
              "id": 4
            }
          ],
          "_id": 142700,
          "id": 3
        }
      ],
      "_id": 142699,
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
  "_id": 142698,
  "id": 1
}
```

Alternatively you can return a list of nodes using the [nodes()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-nodes) function passing the path as parameter:

```
MATCH p = (n:Comment)<-[RELATED_TO*]-(d:Comment)
WHERE NOT (n)-->() AND NOT (d)<--()
return nodes(p)
```

The result will be:

```
╒═════════════════════════════════════╕
│"nodes(p)"                           │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]│
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```